# Characterizing image of group homomorphism based on group order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

> Suppose there is a group homomorphism $\phi: G \to G_0$. If $|G| = 1013$ and $|G_0 | = 55$, what can you say about the image of $G$ under $\phi$?

I get that cardinality of image($\phi$) should divide $55$, by Lagrange theorem.
So it can be 1, 5, 11 or 55. How to proceed from here?

Comment: a) The order of a subgroup must divide the order of the group. b) The order of a quotient group must divide the order of the group

Answer (score 2):

The order of $G$ is prime, so $G$ is simple. Therefore any group homomorphism from $G$ has kernel either $\{e\}$ or the whole $G$. In our case, the former is ruled out because $ϕ$ can't be injective (in fact $1013>55$, see pigeonhole principle); so, we are left with $\operatorname{ker}(ϕ)=G$ and every element of $G$ is mapped to the identity of $G_0$, namely $ϕ(G)=\{e_{G_0}\}$. (For this argument to work, the actual values of $|G|$ and $|G_0|$ are irrelevant, as long as $G$ is simple and $|G_0|<|G|$.)

Answer (score 1):

For every element $g\in G$, let $|g|$ denote the order of $g$, that is the least positive integer $n$ such that $g^n=e$, where $e$ denotes the unit of $G$. Then we have
$$\phi(g)^{|g|}=\phi(g^{|g|})=\phi(e)=e_0$$
where $e_0$ denotes the unit of $G_0$. 
We know also that, if $n$ is an integer such that $g^n=e$, then $|g|$ divides $n$. From our previuos remark we then deduce that $|\phi(g)|$ must divide $|g|$. Since $55$ and $1013$ are coprime, we conclude that $\phi(g)=e_0$.

EDIT: Let $n$ be an integer such that $g^n=e$. By the division Algorithm, we find integers $q, r$ such that $n=q|g|+r$, with $0\leq r<|g|$. Then we have
$$g^r=g^{n-q|g|}=g^n\cdot(g^{|g|})^{-q}=e\cdot e=e$$
But since $|g|$ was least with that property, $r$ must be zero, hence $|g|$ divides $n$.

Comment: |g| is the order . so |g|=n , nthe smallest intger st g^n=e so how do you say |g|/n

Comment: Also how do u connect order with the cardinality that is 1013 and 55?

Comment: The order of an element is the cardinality of the cyclic subgroup generated by that element, which must divide the order of the group by Lagrange

Comment: but what is the diff between n and |g| they are the same rt?

Comment: $n$ is any integer such that $g^n=e$, $|g|$ is the smallest such positive integer

Comment: this n thing is the order of G0 right

Comment: No, you can have $g^n=e$ and $n$ be different to $|g|$. Consider the set $\{n:g^n=e\}$. Then $|g|$ is the minimum of that set.

Comment: yes, if $g^n=e$

Comment: phi(g)^ n = identity of G0 means |g| (order of G , which is 1013 by lagrange), is divisible by order of Image(phi) but the possible orders of Image phi are 1,5 ,11,55 out of only 1 divides 1013 implies that order of image is 1 hence triavial. is this right?@Maryam

Comment: $|g|$ is the order of the element $g$, and it is a divisor of $|G|$, the order of the group $G$. You have proved that $\phi(g)$ divides the order of $G_0$. I have added that it also divides the order of $g$, which is a divisor of the order of $G$. Since the order of $G$ and the order of $G_0$ have no proper common divisors, that number must be $1$.

Comment: noo. i tried to show that order of image divides the order of G. is it right?

Comment: yes, but the order of the image, as you correctly said in your question,  also divides the order of $G_0$, because the image of a homomorphism is a subgroup of the image, and the order of a subgroup divides the order of a group, when the group is finite.

Comment: so this above above comment is right , right?

Comment: yes, the order of the image divides the order of $G$, correct, AND it also divides the order of $G_0$. Conclusion: since the two orders are coprime, that number must be $1$

Comment: thanks @ Maryam

Comment: @Raghu you should really accept this answer